# When trying to load a shapefile into QGIS, a little photograph icon comes up instead of a line.

Tags: qgis

QGIS does not seem to recognize the geometry or extents of the file, even though they must be present, as the site where I got the file includes a preview of the line shapefile over Bing Maps. The shapefile is from PASDA, and all other files I have downloaded from this website have worked without problems. The link to the website is as follows http://www.pasda.psu.edu/uci/DataSummary.aspx?dataset=888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the shapefile (projection/xml as .shp) provided by pasda.psu.edu but if you use the KMZ file you will get the correct location and data, simply load this into qgis and export as a shapefile.

[image]

Using 2.16.1-Nødebo here

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this, but I guess I was using an older version of QGIS